# Can I export table properties using DBeaver?

Tags: database, oracle, export, dbeaver

## Request

I want to list all the table names in a schema in association with the list of that table attributes. I'm using DBeaver, but I can download other software if it works. I don't mind about the output data extension: txt, excel, csv etc., but I'm not searching for an ER diagram.

## Example

If the database schema contains these three tables

**TABLE_A**

| ATTRIBUTE_A_1 | ATTRIBUTE_A_2 | ATTRIBUTE_A_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |

**TABLE_B**

| ATTRIBUTE_B_1 |
| --- |

**TABLE_C**

| ATTRIBUTE_C_1 | ATTRIBUTE_C_2 |
| --- | --- |

I want to extract something like this:

```
TABLE_A
ATTRIBUTE_A_1
ATTRIBUTE_A_2
ATTRIBUTE_A_3

TABLE_B
ATTRIBUTE_B_1

TABLE_C
ATTRIBUTE_C_1
ATTRIBUTE_C_2
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

DBeaver doesn't support "info" and "describe" commands as SQLDeveloper does. You can use a query like "SELECT ... FROM user_tab_columns".

Comment: Thanks, but that query is only for user owned tables as written in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4462.htm#REFRN26277)

Answer (score 0):

I've find out that, in Oracle, it's possible to list all the columns **visible by the user** who executes this query:

```
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
ORDER BY
    TABLE_NAME ASC
```